# Is there a rotation matrix that can invert any 3D vector?

Tags: linear-transformations, 3d, rotations

For example, could a single rotation matrix convert the following vectors:

`vec{1, 1, 1}` to `vec{-1, -1, -1}`

`vec{1, -2, 4}` to `vec{-1, 2, -4}`

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: My thoughts were that each rotation matrix is across an axis.  I was hoping you could use cross product to create an axis that you could easily rotate across to put the vector in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not even products of rotation matrices will be able to do that. In general, rotations preserve orientations (and so have determinant $1$), but in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the map you're describing has determinant $-1$, so no single rotation matrix nor product of them can reflect through the origin. You need to be able to reflect across some plane.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation!